# 'WARNING:: Cannot resolve hostname: [Errno -2] Name or service not known' when trying to connect Zookeeper with Pysolr

Tags: python, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am trying to run a docker-compose that will let me have a Zookeeper ensemble that manages my SolrCloud. Everything runs and from every way I've checked inside the container, my Zookeeper ensemble appears to be up and running. Instead, everytime I try to connect I get an error that the name or service could not be found.

I've tried using different `docker-compose.yml`s, I've tried changing the name of my containers in docker, I've tried changing up the ports in the connection string, I've tried changing the hostname in the connection string, and I've tried the localhost for the connection string.

```
    solr1:
        container_name: solr1
        image: solr:5-slim
        ports:
        - "8981:8983"
        environment:
        - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
        networks:
        - solr
        depends_on:
        - zoo1
        - zoo2
        - zoo3
        volumes:
        - data:/var/solr
        command: >
            sh -c "solr-precreate users"
    solr2:
        image: solr:5-slim
        container_name: solr2
        ports:
        - "8982:8983"
        environment:
        - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
        networks:
        - solr
        depends_on:
        - zoo1
        - zoo2
        - zoo3
    solr3:
        image: solr:5-slim
        container_name: solr3
        ports:
        - "8983:8983"
        environment:
        - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
        ports:
        - 8983:8983
        networks:
        - solr
        depends_on:
        - zoo1
        - zoo2
        - zoo3
    zoo1:
        image: zookeeper:3.4
        container_name: zoo1
        restart: always
        hostname: zoo1
        ports:
        - 2181:2181
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 1
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
        networks:
        - solr
    zoo2:
        image: zookeeper:3.4
        container_name: zoo2
        restart: always
        hostname: zoo2
        ports:
        - 2182:2181
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 2
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
        networks:
        - solr
    zoo3:
        image: zookeeper:3.4
        container_name: zoo3
        restart: always
        hostname: zoo3
        ports:
        - 2183:2181
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 3
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
        networks:
        - solr
```

and then my Python code is

```py
import pysolr

def connect_solrcloud():
    zookeeper = pysolr.ZooKeeper("zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181")
    solr = pysolr.SolrCloud(zookeeper, "users")
    solr.ping()

connect_solrcloud()
```

I would expect that the Zookeeper object is able to connect and then I would be able to access the "users" core I created in my docker container. Instead I get an error saying

```
 WARNING:: Cannot resolve zoo1: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
 WARNING:: Cannot resolve zoo2: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
 WARNING:: Cannot resolve zoo3: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I don't know if this is a docker-compose issue or if it's the way I set Zookeeper up. It appears no one else online has a problem here. They either have problems standing Zookeeper up or some issue once it's connected.

Comment: Where is your python code running?  External to the containers?

Comment: @Martin it's running in my web container. I can post the code for that as well if it helps, but it's within the docker container. I was previously able to use just Solr within my project.

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue. My web container did not include

```
networks:
 - solr
```

so it wasn't able to access zookeeper.